# Append zeros to list

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I have the following input file:

```
a,10,12,13
b,20,22
c,30
d,33
```

and would like to append zeros until each line has three numbers, so this should be the output:

```
a,10,12,13
b,20,22,0
c,30,0,0
d,33,0,0
```

In `sed` I could do use these two commands:

```
sed 's/\([a-z],[0-9]\+$\)/\1,0,0/g'
sed 's/\([a-z],[0-9]\+,[0-9]\+$\)/\1,0/g'
```

My regex knowledge is limited to `sed` and I would like to know how to achieve this with `awk` or `perl`.

Comment: I see that you've added an `awk` tag, but I don't see any awk code in your question. Could you add some? I'd love to help, but I don't think that sed is the best tool for something like this. :-)

Comment: I also think `awk` is better than `sed` for this particular job but I'm a beginner with `awk` so I need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=2;i<=4;i++) $i+=0} 1' file
a,10,12,13
b,20,22,0
c,30,0,0
d,33,0,0
```

Answer (score 5):

As a Perl one-liner

```
perl -pe 's/$/,0/ until tr/,// >= 3' myfile
```

#### output

```
a,10,12,13
b,20,22,0
c,30,0,0
d,33,0,0
```

Answer (score 4):

Super simple in awk.

```
$ awk -F, '{for(;NF<4;$(NF+1)=0);} 1' OFS=, i.csv
```

This uses a for loop whose condition is your field count goal and whose action adds another field. This works in BSD awk and GNU awk, I haven't tested in mawk or other awks.

In sed, however, the solution looks a little more complicated.

```
$ sed -e ':start' -e '/,.*,.*,/b end' -e 's/$/,0/' -e 'b start' -e ':end' i.csv
```

Or more compactly:

```
$ sed -e ':start
  /,.*,.*,/b end
  s/$/,0/
  b start
  :end' i.csv
```

The strategy here is to test for four fields by looking for three field separators, then step through a loop that adds a `,0` until we pass that test, at which point we `b end` (branch to the `:end` label) to quit. Then print the line, as it's the default action.

This was tested in BSD sed, but should be equally compatible (and perhaps more compactable) in GNU sed.

Comment: I get syntax error at the closing brace (`}`) for the command `awk -F, '{for(;NF<4;$(NF+1)=0)} 1' OFS=,  inputfile`

Answer (score 4):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -F, -lane 'print join ",", @F, (0)x(3-$#F)' ip.txt
a,10,12,13
b,20,22,0
c,30,0,0
d,33,0,0

$ perl -F, -lane 'print join ",", @F, ("NA")x(3-$#F)' ip.txt
a,10,12,13
b,20,22,NA
c,30,NA,NA
d,33,NA,NA
```

- `-F,` input field delimiter is `,` and results are accessible from `@F` array

  - See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches for command line option details
- `(0)x(3-$#F)` add missing zeroes. `$#F` gives index of last element, for example it is `2` for the second line - so `3-2` zeroes added

  - `("NA")x(3-$#F)` to use `NA` instead of `0` as filler element
- `join ","` use `,` as delimiter to join array elements

Inspired from [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)'s answer

```
$ perl -pe 's|$|",0" x (3 - tr/,//)|e' ip.txt 
a,10,12,13
b,20,22,0
c,30,0,0
d,33,0,0
```

- `e` modifier allows to use Perl code in replacement section
- `tr/,//` will give number of `,` in input line
- `x` will repeat the given string by `(3 - tr/,//)`

Answer (score 3):

Following `awk` may help here too.

```
awk -F, 'NF<4{i="";while(i<(4-NF)){val=val?val OFS "0":",0";i++}}{print $0 val;val=""}' OFS=,  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F, '
NF<4{
  i="";
  while(i<(4-NF)){
    val=val?val OFS "0":",0";
    i++}
}
{
  print $0 val;
  val=""
}' OFS=,  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";nf=4}{for(i=(NF+1);i<=nf;i++)$i=0}1' file
a,10,12,13
b,20,22,0
c,30,0,0
d,33,0,0
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","               # separators
    nf=4                     # desired field count
}
{
    for(i=(NF+1);i<=nf;i++)  # da loop to create new fields
        $i=0                 # set new fields to 0 
}1' file                     # output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$3==""{$3="0"}$4==""{$4="0"}1' file

a,10,12,13
b,20,22,0
c,30,0,0
d,33,0,0
```

First it says to keep the field separator in the output as well and then fill empty fields in $3,$4 with zeros.